# Intel 8260 wireless adapter unclaimed on 20.10 groovy kernel 5.8.0-26-generic

Tags: networking, kernel, network-manager, iwlwifi

After updating to groovy, and then the kernel was updated at some point now I have to boot into 5.8.0-25-generic to use my wireless. Below is the output of lshw -C network on both.
Is this a bug in the latest kernel missing the correct firmware? Or somehow it cannot claim the interface with the latest firmware?
There seems to have been some work done on the linux-firmware package in the past month https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux...962e5c7316924b
I can't be certain if this is where the issue is though. Anything else that can be done or checked?

The firmware seems to be present

```
/lib/firmware$ ll iwlwifi-8*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1745176 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2351636 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2394060 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2120860 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2227284 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2310116 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2448976 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2401100 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2389968 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1811984 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2234528 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2307104 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2440780 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2409984 Oct 28 13:51 iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
```

5.8.0-25-generic

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 00:c2:c6:bc:22:58
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-25-generic firmware=36.79ff3ccf.0 8000C-36.ucode ip=192.168.50.229 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:df100000-df101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 21
       serial: b8:ae:ed:ea:91:9e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:124 memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

5.8.0-26-generic

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df100000-df101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 21
       serial: b8:ae:ed:ea:91:9e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
```

UPDATE: I actually noticed that in 5.8.0-26-generic a lot of kernel modules are not loaded.  Maybe this is not an issue with the driver/firmware.

5.8.0-26-generic lsmod

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rpcsec_gss_krb5        40960  0
auth_rpcgss           114688  1 rpcsec_gss_krb5
nfsv4                 745472  0
nfs                   344064  1 nfsv4
lockd                 106496  1 nfs
grace                  16384  1 lockd
fscache               376832  2 nfsv4,nfs
nf_tables             196608  0
nfnetlink              16384  1 nf_tables
binfmt_misc            24576  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
kvm_intel             282624  0
kvm                   724992  1 kvm_intel
joydev                 28672  0
input_leds             16384  0
efi_pstore             16384  0
video                  49152  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
sunrpc                495616  6 nfsv4,auth_rpcgss,lockd,rpcsec_gss_krb5,nfs
drm                   565248  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               45056  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  3
dm_crypt               49152  1
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   135168  2 usbhid,hid_generic
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  2
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
nvme                   45056  3
e1000e                274432  0
nvme_core             110592  5 nvme
xhci_pci               20480  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
```

5.8.0-25-generic lsmod

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  4
nf_tables             196608  0
nfnetlink              16384  1 nf_tables
nfsv3                  49152  1
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsv3
rpcsec_gss_krb5        40960  0
auth_rpcgss           114688  1 rpcsec_gss_krb5
nfsv4                 745472  0
nfs                   344064  3 nfsv4,nfsv3
lockd                 106496  2 nfsv3,nfs
grace                  16384  1 lockd
fscache               376832  2 nfsv4,nfs
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  13
algif_hash             16384  6
algif_skcipher         16384  6
af_alg                 28672  26 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
binfmt_misc            24576  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   131072  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
snd_hda_intel          53248  2
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
coretemp               20480  0
snd_usb_audio         286720  1
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
kvm_intel             282624  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm                   724992  1 kvm_intel
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
rapl                   20480  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
iwlmvm                405504  0
mac80211              917504  1 iwlmvm
btusb                  57344  0
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
joydev                 28672  0
input_leds             16384  0
btintel                28672  1 btusb
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
uvcvideo               98304  0
snd_pcm               118784  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
bluetooth             602112  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
iwlwifi               364544  1 iwlmvm
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
cfg80211              782336  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
efi_pstore             16384  0
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch    16384  0
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
snd                    94208  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
ee1004                 20480  0
mei_me                 40960  1
roles                  16384  1 intel_xhci_usb_role_switch
soundcore              16384  1 snd
8250_dw                16384  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
mei                   110592  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
ir_rc6_decoder         20480  0
rc_rc6_mce             16384  0
ite_cir                28672  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
videodev              245760  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     57344  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
sunrpc                495616  20 nfsv4,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfsv3,rpcsec_gss_krb5,nfs_acl,nfs
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               45056  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  4
dm_crypt               49152  1
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   135168  2 usbhid,hid_generic
i915                 2273280  24
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
aesni_intel           372736  25
drm_kms_helper        225280  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cryptd                 24576  9 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
e1000e                274432  0
nvme                   45056  3
i2c_i801               32768  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
rc_core                53248  5 ite_cir,ir_rc6_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,cec
sdhci_pci              57344  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
drm                   565248  8 drm_kms_helper,i915
cqhci                  32768  1 sdhci_pci
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
nvme_core             110592  5 nvme
sdhci                  69632  1 sdhci_pci
idma64                 20480  0
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
xhci_pci               20480  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
video                  49152  1 i915
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
```

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: No, there are no other operating systems.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux`.

Comment: the body is too long now, the output is here https://pastebin.com/FyFEDbuq

Comment: hmm looks like linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-26-generic is missing?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `5.8.0-26` is not fully installed for some reason.

Run

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-26-generic
```

to install the rest of the kernel.

This happened because `linux-generic` meta package is missing. It pulss all necessary kernel packages. Install it by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Otherwise you won't get kernel updates.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am not able to find that repo in /etc/apt/sources.list in order to disable it.
Should the kernel from the proposed repo be removed as well to avoid more issues?
Thanks again!

Comment: Add output of `apt policy linux-image-5.8.0-26-generic`.

Comment: `$ apt policy linux-image-5.8.0-26-generic
linux-image-5.8.0-26-generic:
  Installed: 5.8.0-26.27
  Candidate: 5.8.0-26.27
  Version table:
 *** 5.8.0-26.27 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: Hm...It looks like it is in the `main` already. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses :)  what would cause linux-generic and the modules-extra packages from not being installed?  Am i missing a repo or something?

Comment: It is hard to tell. Maybe you removed some kernel packages and that removed the meta. Maybe the upgrade from a previous release was not correct, etc. Anyway it should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks again, i am getting this error now, should the linux-generic be installed first?

Comment: Boot with the previous kernel and do it from there. You need an internet connection.

Comment: i am trying from the previous kernel, 
`dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-26-generic_5.8.0-26.27_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/modules/5.8.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/media/dvb-frontends/dib8000.ko.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-26-generic_5.8.0-26.27_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Run `sudo apt clean && sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-26-generic`

Comment: thanks again.  i also needed to disable sophos, ugh 
`$ systemctl stop sav-protect.service`